# EditText cursor resides after the hint

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a simple sign in `activity` in my app with email and password fields. There is a strange problem with the `hint` and `cursor` position in the email `EditText`:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, by default, the `cursor` isn't at the first position. It is shown **after the hint** (as if the `hint` is an input text)

As far as the `layout` goes, the password `EditText` is the same as the email one, but it doesn't have this problem:

[image]

Anyone has any clue why this happens? And how can I solve it?

---

Here's the activity's layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
            android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <!-- sign in button -->

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="120dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_background_login_and_offered_and_followers"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="signInButton"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in_register" />

            <!-- sign up button -->

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/sign_up_button"
                android:layout_width="120dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sign_in_button"
                android:background="@color/Gray"
                android:onClick="signUpButton"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_up_register" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

If any other code part is needed, please tell me to add it.

Comment: That is rather strange. Can you reproduce the problem across environments, such as it happening both on a device and on an emulator? Also, what version of Android are you testing this on? I am no language expert, but that script looks a bit like Arabic. If so, perhaps try `android:gravity="start"` instead of `android:gravity="left"`, to see if Android's RTL support is what is tripping you up. This might require `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your `<application>` in the manifest: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: I am testing on Nexus 4 with Android 4.4 (I don't have an emulator setup to test on). The texts are Farsi actually. I have `android:supportsRtl="true"` in my manifest. Changing to `android:gravity="start"` makes the cursor to goe right and **at the start of the hint**. But I want it to be on the left.

Comment: "The texts are Farsi actually" -- my apologies for guessing the wrong script. "But I want it to be on the left" -- you could try `android:gravity="end"` and see what that does.

Comment: Sadly, changing the gravity to "end" doesn't help. The cursor still is the same position as before. What puzzles me is the difference between EditTexts... Also, I checked on a Galaxy Mini with Android 2.3, it didn't have the problem.

Comment: "I checked on a Galaxy Mini with Android 2.3, it didn't have the problem" -- that's because 2.3 had limited RTL support. The stuff that you're using was added in 4.2 and beyond. And that stuff is going to want your Farsi to start on the right. To me, this feels like a framework bug, but I am not strong enough on RTL support to know for certain.

Comment: OK. Thanks anyway. Maybe you're right and it's a bug. I'll wait to see if others can suggest solutions.

Comment: @Mahm00d Farsi is from right to left or left to right language?

Comment: @ZohraKhan, it's right to left, the same as Arabic. Of course, as emails are in English and passwords are often in English, too, the EditTexts are left-aligned.

Comment: hey man. I have exact the same problem! let me know if you found the answer yet

Comment: @Alireza, Sure. I can confirm as of android 4.4.4, the problem still exists...

Answer (score 8):

Try this code:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection(android.text.Spannable, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29)
 A simple `yourEditText.setSelection(0);` should suffice

Comment: Adding `setSelection(0)` didn't solve it. The EditText actually has a zero length, but the cursor is not at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
android:gravity="left|center"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you want to have Persian hint for your EditText ( It should be RTL) and LTR input text ( like email, password and.... )

In my apps I do this, In XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="ایمیل را وارد نمائید" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

And in Java:

```
final EditText  editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        editTxt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (editTxt.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    editTxt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                else {
                    editTxt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

It give me, my goal result. hint aligned in right and when user start typing, typed text aligned to left, by this way cursor issue will solve too :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But you misunderstood. I want both the hint and the text to be left-aligned (EditText is left-aligned without problem). The problem is when Persian hint is written inside a left-aligned EditText, the cursor resides after the text, not at the beginning of the hint.

Comment: Aha, then as you can see, when you set inputType property True, wonderfully everything goes as like as you want! then go and check EditText Source Code it can be useful for you (I'll do that as soon as possible :D)

Comment: What do you mean setting inputType to True? It gets values like `"text"`,`"number"`,... not boolean... And as you can see in my code, it is set as `"textEmailAddress"`.

Comment: Sorry for my bad, My means was you set this attribute with value like textPassword

Answer (score 0):

After five years, we still have this problem. What I come up with which makes cursor a little less uglier is using `android:textDirection="ltr"` or `android:textDirection="rtl"` for all EditTexts. It would force cursor to go to the end/start of hint, and of course we can still use gravity to put hints in the center or whatever we want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextInputEditText and also use android:textAlignment="viewStart"

here is an Example:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingHorizontal="25dp"
                    android:paddingVertical="10dp"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```